# What happens if a Canadian is convicted (misdemeanour)in Europe? Is the Canadian government notified?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, germany, criminal-record

A Canadian person is convicted of a misdemeanour while in Germany. The person gets a criminal record in Germany. Will the information about the conviction be sent to Canada? Will it appear in the Canadian database?

Comment: Most misdemeanors ("Ordnungswidrigkeit") don't show up on the criminal record in [tag:germany].

Comment: @Trish I think – considering North American usage – KellyK means _misdemeanor_, § 12 (2) StGB. In fact no administrative offenses are eligible to get listed in the criminal record.

Proving unreliable to possess a firearm or handle explosives may be due to administrative offenses, but the administration’s decision is logged, not any administrative offense leading to this assessment.

Answer (score 4):

There is no systemic process by which convictions of crime in Germany (at all, let alone for misdemeanors) are reported to authorities in Canada.

This said, a Canadian charged with a crime in Germany has a right to consular assistance (i.e. to call upon the Canadian embassy for help). And, if the Canadian actually does obtain assistance from the Canadian government in defense of criminal charges and is convicted anyway, obviously, a Canadian government official will know about it.

I don't know if Canadian diplomats who provide consular assistance who learn of criminal convictions of Canadians abroad report those convictions to criminal record database record keepers in Canada, although I suspect that they do not.